# Flutter SDK Path on Mac

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

I seemed to have messed up my PATH to the Flutter SDK on my MAC. I am a windows user so I am not familiar with MAC's file system or settings. Here is what I get when I ECHO it.

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/sacromer/flutter/bin

How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you want it to be, it has ~/flutter/bin in there... the SDK path is probably not related PATH variable, that is for executables

Comment: you probably need some CFLAGS="-I/path/to/includes -L/path/to/libs" or similar (I don't know what flutter is assuming it is a Cish SDK but if it is something else... then it would be different env vars)

Comment: It is in my Downloads folder so whatever path that is.

Comment: are you following a tutorial? can you put it in ~/flutter, such that your bin dir will be in the path?

Comment: The flutter commands aren’t working so the path is wrong

Comment: I followed a tutorial. I have been developing on Windows with flutter for a year now and just started with a Mac

Comment: so if there is a folder called flutter in your user's directory and in that there was a folder called bin the executable contents of that would be found without having to type the whole path...

Comment: So how would I fix it? Does the path have to change or can I just move the folder and it will work? That path when I echo it looks like a bunch of junk but Im a windows developer

Comment: I put it in flutter directory same problem

Comment: Where did you declare the PATH variable and how did you add the Flutter SDK to it?

Comment: Terminal is where I added it according to the steps on the flutter / Mac install directions